# Handle digital certificate using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a website automation for bank website using selenium in Python in which I am able to open internet explorer and then website , when I am trying to login after inserting user credentials , a security window open to select digital certificate of hdfc bank website.
Please tell me how to select digital certificate from that window,due to privacy I cannot share screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

There are various ways to handle it.

**1. Use capabilities :**

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
```

**2. Use browser profiles :**

```
FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```